# Reading a tab separated file using delimiter

Tags: python

I am using the following to read a tab separated file. There are three columns in the file but the first column is being ignored when I print the column header only. How can I include the first column, too?

```
f = open("/tmp/data.txt")
for l in f.readlines():
    print l.strip().split("\t")
    break
    f.close()
```

Output:

```
['session_id\t', '\tevent_id_concat']
```

The first column name is `id` where it is not printed in the above array.

`print l` yields the following:

```
'id\tsession_id\tevent_id_concat\r\n'
```

Output:

```
['id\t', '\tevent_id_concat']
```

Comment: It should work. Can you add `print l` before your `print` statement and show the output? P.S. Also, no need for `.readlines()` here, pretty much as always.

Comment: I think [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) will do the job.

Comment: Can you actually show the output of `print repr(l)`?

Comment: Yeah that's probably what I wanted :)

Comment: Suddenly i noticed its not the id column that i am missing but the missing column is session_id

Comment: `'id\tsession_id\tevent_id_concat\r\n'.strip().split('\t')` gives `['id', 'session_id', 'event_id_concat']` for me. Are you sure you show the actual code that's executed?

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest to use the csv module. It is easy to use and fits best if you want to read in table like structures stored in a CSV like format (tab/space/something else delimited).

The [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) gives good examples where the simplest usage is stated to be:

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/data.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Every row is a list which is very usefull if you want to do index based manipulations.

If you want to change the delimiter there is a keyword for this but I am often fine with the predefined dialects which can also be defined via a keyword.

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/data.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

I am not sure if this will fix your problems but the use of elaborated modules will ensure you that something is wrong with your file and not your code if the error will remain.

Comment: There is no need to do `reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')`, there is an 'excel-tab' format defined so you can simply use that rather than tweaking the 'excel' format: `reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel-tab')`

Answer (score 7):

It should work but it is better to use 'with':

```
with open('/tmp/data.txt') as f:
   for l in f:
       print l.strip().split("\t")
```

if it doesn't then probably your file doesn't have the required format.

Comment: But how can `strip` strip off a word?

Comment: The module based approach should be preferred as it handles the many possible edge cases