# File reading in python based on '.'(period)

Tags: python-2.7

How to read lines from file in python based on period and not '\n' given that '.' in not a token itself but a part of word which ends the sentence. eg: I like StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python reading a tab separated file using delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229643/python-reading-a-tab-separated-file-using-delimiter)

Comment: With '.' it had other problems like countering abbreviations. However its solved now using nltk sentence tokenizer. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Great that you found an answer.  You can post it as an answer, and then mark it as an answer -- this could help someone with the same problem later; they'll find that you asked the question and it has an answer, and they'll know what to do too!