# How do you import a txt file and create a two column table splitting on /t?

Tags: python, split

I am trying to import a file.txt and read it as alist with two columns
the Format of the txt file is as follows.

```
1 1.234567
2 2.345678
```

Thank you

I can open it as a list but I couldt split \t so I could get two rows.

```
o=open('file.txt')
csv_o = csv.reader(o)
for line in csv_o:

        print (line)
o.close()
```

What I get is

```
['1\t1.234567']
['2\t2.345678']
```

and What I want is

```
['1','1.234567']
['2','2.345678']
```

Comment: `csv.reader(o, delimiter='\t')` this is almost the [first example in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Comment: Or just `first, second = line.split('\t')`. I find it hard to believe that you performed any searching at all before asking here.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I searched but i am really a beginner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python reading a tab separated file using delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229643/python-reading-a-tab-separated-file-using-delimiter)

Answer (score 2):

Use `delimiter="\t"`

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(filename) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```