# How can I read from a file while differentiating the variables?

Tags: python, function, file

I just started studying Python and I have homework that I don't know how to begin with.

I have to read info about the employees of a company: `name, age, occupation, salary, years_in_the company` from a (txt) file. They are found on separate lines, and are split by a tab, for example:

```
Helen   20  Network Designer    5449    9
Jasmine 40  Software Architect  2536    1
Phoebe  28  Software Engineer   2627    7
Aysha   34  Software Developer  6441    3
```

Now, with this info I have to create a few functions like the average age of the employees, best-paid job, best-paid employee and so on. I do not know how to properly read the data from the file and how to implement the functions. I was thinking to define the functions at first, and then read all the data from the file, but a friend of mine told me that I could define each function and inside it I could read the necessary data.

For example, if I were to calculate the average age of the employees, I was thinking about doing it like this:

```
 def avg(*args):
        count = len(args)
        if args > 0:
            age_sum = 0
            for i in args:
                age_sum += i
            return age_sum / count
        else:
            return 0
```

The problem is, I don't know how to fetch the proper data to the function. Can anyone please help me understand how to do it properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python reading a tab separated file using delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229643/python-reading-a-tab-separated-file-using-delimiter)

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very broad question that seems to have many smaller questions inside it. Especially when asking/answering homework questions, it's going to be very dependent on what you've learned in your class and what you are/aren't allowed to use. Rather than asking "How do I", it would be better to try some things based on your research, then ask specific questions with a specific [mcve] if you get stuck

Comment: I suggest that you start with something small and then build up from there. For example, you could figure out how to read a file one line at a time and print out each line. When you can do this much, you figure out the next small part that you can change to do something else. Each of these little steps will eventually build towards the complete program.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one way, but there might best way than this to do that, but at least this will help you to deal with your problem. You can optimize the code plus you can change the variable from int to float for better coverage of avg etc and there should not be an empty line between lines in the file.

```
#print all detail
def print_all():
  file = open("data.txt","r")
  for line in file:  
    fields = line.split(" ")
    print  ("name "+ fields[0])
    print  ("age "+ fields[1])
    print  ("occupation "+ fields[2])
    print  ("type occupation "+ fields[3])
    print  ("salary "+ fields[4])
    print  ("years_in_the_company "+ fields[5])
  file.close()
# avg salary
def avg__salary(employ = "salary" ):
  file = open("data.txt","r")
  avg=0
  for salary in file:
      salary_field = salary.split(" ")
      avg=avg+int(salary_field[4])
  file.close()
  return avg
# avg age
def avg__age(employ = "age" ):
  file = open("data.txt","r")
  avg_age=0
  for age in file:
      age_field = age.split(" ")
      avg_age=avg_age+int(age_field[1])
  file.close()
  return avg_age

# best paid job
def best_paid(employ = "paid" ):
  file = open("data.txt","r")
  bestpaid=0
  for age in file:
      age_field = age.split(" ")
      if bestpaid < age_field[4]:
         bestpaid=age_field[4]
  file.close()
  return bestpaid

number_of_lines=open('data.txt', 'r').read().count("\n") 
print("All employ detail")
print_all()
print("Avg salary is",avg__salary()/number_of_lines)
print("Avg age is",avg__age()/number_of_lines)
print("Best paid is",best_paid())
```

Comment: Razvan you can try this.